# SVG lines disappearing on scaling down

Tags: firefox, svg

I am using  elements of width 1.5 to connect  elements. This all looks fine but if the image is dynamically scaled down to show more of the diagram then some of the lines eventually disappear in Firefox but not in Chrome. Is this a problem in the Firefox SVG support, or some difference in default settings that I can change?

Rather than present any code, I can point to an example in a blog-post at: https://parallax-viewpoint.blogspot.com/2018/12/further-travels-of-walking-boots.html. Scroll to the bottom of the post and there's an embedded SVG "family tree" image that uses the JavaScript pan-zoom library to dynamically scale the diagram.

On the default setting, in Firefox, not all lines will show -- probably dependent upon whether they fall on a pixel boundary or not. As the image is gradually scaled up, you will notice that the lines will eventually all show. Contrast this with Chrome where the lines always appear to show.

**New information from Firefox support:** there is a pronounced "redraw" fluctuation for all transformations (+ or -) from the initial position. The lines are markedly thinner after the redraw, and this suggests some sort of rounding error is occurring.

Comment: Try using `vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke"` for your lines

Comment: Thanks but wouldn't that prevent the lines scaling up as well? When scaling the diagram up, the lines scale correctly, so it's only when scaling down that Firefox seems to make them disappear.

Comment: Draw 2 lines on top of each other, one with non-scaling-stroke, the other without.

Comment: Thanks Robert. That makes sense, although I'd have to encapsulate it somehow to avoid the code getting unmanageable. It would also show up a problem with opacity with my current settings: one would show through the other. I admit to being surprised by the Chrome/Firefox difference, and wondered whether it was one of the many SVG settings that was different.

Comment: Robert's suggestion also causes problems when joining lines. I already have problems joining them seamlessly -- either leaving gaps on corners or showing overlap density. These are fixable (when I get time) but if I have 2 sets of lines with different stroke widths then it's a bit of a mess. I've also updated the question with new information.

Comment: There's nothing in the SVG specification that says stroke has to always always be visible regardless of stroke-width/scaling. All browsers have rounding in various places to try to make drawings look reasonable, that rounding is different in different browsers and while it improves many documents, it adversely affects some.

Answer (score 1):

The suggestion of using double lines (one with non-scaling-stroke and one without) runs into a few issues. If the line elements have stroke-opacity less then 1 then the superposition shows through. Also, with SVG 1.1, it does not appear to be possible to encapsulate the drawing of two lines in a single group/symbol if the line lengths are related but not equal. Unequal lengths are necessary to prevent corner gaps where orthogonal lines don't reach fully into the corners. Using calc() to adjust one length relative to a 100% length doesn't work with line elements because they use pairs of coordinates rather than lengths. I tried using a rect in place of a line but Firefox did not support CSS control over its width/height in order to use calc().

The solution was simply to use opaque lines (stroke-opacity=1.0), suggesting that the disappearance of the lines was due to Firefox's handling of stroke-opacity < 1.0. It may be the case that lines will eventually disappear at minute scales, but the reported problem was specifically that Firefox lost them much earlier than it should, and compared the situation with Chrome (which worked OK).